# How to convert ResponseEntity body or ResponseEntity to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, httpresponse

```
ResponseEntity<CustomObject> response;
```

I need to be able to convert either `ResponseEntity<CustomObject> or CustomObject to byte[]`

I have tried multiple ways

```
 SerializationUtils.serialize(response.getBody())
 ByteArrayOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream
```

But I am getting `NotSerializableException`. Can someone please help me?

Edit: Implementing Serializable helps in converting CustomObject. Can someone please help me to convert ResponseEntity to byte array?

Comment: just curious. Why would you want to convert it to bytes? Why not communicate using json?

Comment: I encrypt the byte array and build response. On the receiving end, I decrypt and should be able to get the original response back. If I convert custom object alone into byte array, I am not able to get my original response back

Answer (score 0):

Does CustomObject implements Serializable interface?

If not just add it and try again.

Comment: thanks, that helps for converting CustomObject to byte array, but If I try to convert the ResponseEntity<CustomObject> itself to bytearray, I get the same exception.